# HTML Upload to certain directory in website

Tags: html, file-upload, upload

I have some code for an HTML upload form:

```
<form name="Upload FILE" action="mailto:emailaddresshere" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="uploadField" />
</form>
```

The above form uploads a file and sends it to a set email address. Is it possible to instead make it upload a file, and place it on the web server at a certain directory? Preferably pure HTML, no PHP *if possible!*

Thanks!

Comment: HTML is a client side Markup language for displaying documents. If you want to save a file to disk then you HAVE to use PHP.

Comment: Or any other server side language like ASP, Python, Ruby on rails. there are plenty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without a server-side language. HTML is client-side and has nothing to do with servers.

When a request is made to a server, something needs to be there to figure out what to do. That's where PHP comes in (or any other server-side language).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess I'll have to use PHP then... :/